# App Engine Endpoints DOWN

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I use Google Cloud Endpoints for my application.  Whenever I hit the application root, it gives an error.  The console says:

```
Importing endpoints from google.appengine.ext is deprecated and will be removed.  Add the endpoints library to app.yaml, then endpoints can be imported simply with "import endpoints".
```

There is no mention of this in the documentation and I believe I am doing this correctly.

I tried adding endpoints to the library section of `app.yaml`, but the deployment failed saying that it wasn't a valid library.  When I look in the instance page, it says that my instances are running on **App Engine 1.8.5**, which is a pre-release version that hasn't even come out yet!

Is this a Google problem or something with my code?

Comment: I am also having the same issue, the prerelease post in the group also does not mention this deprecation!

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/0fq4FIVH55o

Apparently its removed for Python2.5! Without warning...
RuntimeError: Endpoints library isn't available in python 2.5 runtime. Use the python27 runtime instead.

Comment: My app is COMPLETELY down due to this issue and I can't contact Google for support.  This is a BIG PROBLEM with App Engine - why hasn't it been fixed yet??

Comment: Posted on the app engine forum and the issue tracker
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/U2CDQy3UEPI

Comment: Looks like an issue is already open

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10004

Answer (score 1):

The message you're seeing is a warning, not an error. Endpoints running on Python 2.7 will continue to work without code changes.

However, you may also be seeing an error if you're trying to run Endpoints on Python 2.5. This will no longer work, and unfortunately was not well communicated prior to the release. To resume use of Endpoints, you'll need to update your application to Python 2.7.