# 1.8.5 Prelease Accidentally in Production

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

As mentioned in my other question [from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985115/app-engine-endpoints-down), my app has been somehow moved to 1.8.5 in production.  Google Cloud Endpoints is completely broken in this release, asking me to put `endpoints` in the library section of `app.yaml`.  When I do that and deploy, App Engine rejects the app.yaml file saying the library isn't valid.

Right now, every call to my app is hitting a 500 error because the endpoints library is DEPRECATED and I can't access the "new" way of importing it.  1.8.5 is a prerelease version and I dont know how in the world it's on production.

I NEED HELP FIXING THIS ISSUE.

[image: 1.8.5 in production]

Comment: Have you logged an issue ?

Comment: I think an issue is more for when you know what the issue is and are reporting on a bug you need fixed.  Otherwise, it seems to me that Google wants people to look for support here on SO (though they rarely provide it themselves and rarely warn of breaking changes to endpoints).

Comment: google cloud endpoints is in preview and should never be used in production. According to the note on top of the api it's not covered by SLA or deprecation policy.

Comment: Production Issues belong in the tracker, not on StackOverflow: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue

Comment: Thanks everyone. I added a production issue to the App Engine issue tracker [here.](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10012&thanks=10012&ts=1380133943)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK now available on the Eclipse plugins.